# what is the difference between link type and protocal type in payment gateway intigration

Tags: payment-gateway

I am looking to add payment gateway to my application. i am using GMO payment gateway. there are 3 connection types available 1.link type 2.module type  3. protocal type.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Connection Types section of https://www.gmo-pg.com/en/service/mulpay/developer/spec/ and experience with other payment gateways

1. Link type: GMO host pages to take the payment, you will redirect users to these, to take the payment
2. Module type: GMO provide a Java/PHP library, which you will call from your own Java/PHP code and this will communicate with their servers to handle the payment
3. Protocol type: GMO will provide an HTTPS api, and you will make requests to  endpoints on this, to take payment

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to integrate with protocol type

Comment: @PraneethKumar you will almost certainly need to contact GMO to get a test account set up and to find out what the endpoints you need to call. Their documentation will tell you what you need to do